# Prediction of sets

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, probability, prediction

Assume I have 4 transactions A,A,A,B. Also assume, A has been grouped with B into a single group. There are similar transactions where say C,C,G,C,C,C and C,C,B,C and C,C,B,C,C are also grouped. Here we see that C has been grouped with B and G but C&B have been grouped twice compared to C&G There are lots of transactions like these.

When a new set of transactions come say C,C,B,A,A,G I need to suggest for each of these transactions, what other transactions it should be paired with. So in this example, the prediction should be as follows.

```
C -> B (Predicted since it had max probability)
C -> B (Predicted since it had max probability)
B -> C (Predicted)
A -> B (Predicted)
A -> B (Predicted)
G -> C (Predicted)
```

1) For this simple case what approach/ ML technique is needed to achieve this?
2) If the transactions become more complicated where A,A,A,B,N are grouped, how will I be able to handle this case.

I can go through the transactions and calculate the probability of each transactions in a group, but is there a better approach I should be considering. Are some packages available for these problems?

Comment: It seems like you are leaving something out in your description, because you seem to be referring to these both as grouped events and as individual events.  For instance if they are grouped events then you can binarize your data and solve this as a supervised learning classification problem, but the predictions you give in the example are for single values.  But for single values you leave out the most likely cases where A->A and C->C.  Do you mean single events where you are trying to figure out the maximum liklihood of switching from one value to another value?

Comment: @AN6U5 : I am sorry for the confusion there. The goal is to predict what transactions are likely to be grouped together (other than itself)  First, there are individual transactions which have grouped like the examples above. Hence the training data is a group of transactions. Now when new transactions (individual) come, I need to suggest the other transactions that it is to be grouped with based on the previous grouping I have. Does this help?

Comment: From the example result, what I mean is that, if a C transactions comes, then the program should suggest that it should be paired with a transaction of type B,similarly B with C, A with B  and G with C

Comment: @AN6U5: That is what I have given as 2 different questions here. 1) Only 2 different transactions per group 2) More than 2. Answer to anything would really help! :)

Comment: I think in first example you provided "C" is more probable than "B" to come after "C", isn't it?

Comment: @Vasei :It is not a sequence I want here, what I want is that 'B' is most probable to be grouped with 'C' than 'G', hence for a transaction 'C' , I need to predict that it should be grouped with 'B'.